# Problema com interrupção serial USART UDRE para ATMega328p

Tags: c, arduino, serial

Estou com problema na utilização de interrupção de transmissão serial USART em um programa feito em puro C e rodado em arduino (Atmega 328p).

Minha aplicação exige puro C por motivos de eficiência e velocidade, mas ainda quero manter comunicação serial para debug e impressão de informações em tempo real.

A seguir segue uma representação mínima do programa

O problema é na interrupção, estou com problema nela, já tentei usar TX na interrupção, porém gera dados inconsistentes na saída e, como quero utilizar método do vetor circular, o registrador UDRE parece a melhor forma, adicionando a isso, o programa exemplo achado no site http://jamesgregson.blogspot.com.br/2012/07/sample-code-for-atmega328p-serial.html funciona melhor.

Em resumo, a interrupção não é executada, pois o programa fica preso no `while`. Como posso resolver isso? Posso desabilitar a interrupção no meio 
dela?

O programa está sendo compilado pelo AVR-GCC no IDE codeblocks e o exemplo dado no site referenciado anteriormente funciona, mas não é o que a aplicação exige.

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<avr/interrupt.h>

//void intToStr(unsigned long, char*);
#define USART_BAUDRATE 57600
#define BAUD_PRESCALE (((F_CPU/(USART_BAUDRATE*16UL)))-1)

char ok = 0;


ISR(UART_UDRE_vect)
{
    ok = 1;
    UCSR0B &= ~(1<<5);
}

int main(void){


    UBRR0H  = (BAUD_PRESCALE >> 8);
    UBRR0L  = BAUD_PRESCALE;
    UCSR0B |= (1<<TXEN0);
    UCSR0C |= (1<<UCSZ00) | (1<<UCSZ01);
    sei();

    UCSR0B |= (1<<5);
    while(1){

        // write the byte to the serial port
        UDR0 = '0';
        UCSR0B |= (1<<5);
        while(ok != 1){}

        UDR0 = '\n';
        UCSR0B |= (1<<5);
        while(ok != 1){}
    }
    return 0;

}
```